# Vue.js: How do you call component specific methods outside of component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webrtc, opentok

The goal here is to use OpenTok WebRTC platform for a video chat web app built with vue. Here is an example of [OpenTok in Vue](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Vue-Basic-Video-Chat).

I'm getting confused on where to call specific methods for the publisher because it is nested within a session.vue component. I want to call methods such as:

1) Stop publishing
2) Change the publisher to source from a video instead of webcam

This is the [web API](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html).

Should I write methods that affect the publisher in the child component publisher.vue or should I do that in the parent component which calls publisher?

Publisher.vue

```
<template>
    <div> </div>
</template>

<script>
import OT from "@opentok/client";

export default {
    name: "publisher",
    props: {
        session: {
            type: OT.Session,
            required: false
        },
        rlive: Boolean,
        opts: {
            type: Object,
            required: false
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        // console.log(this.rlive)
        console.log("publisher created")
        console.log(this.session)
        const publisher = OT.initPublisher(this.$el, this.opts, err => {
            if (err) {
                this.$emit("error", err);
            } else {
                this.$emit("publisherCompleted");
            }
        });
        this.$emit("publisherCreated", publisher);

        const publish = () => {
            this.session.publish(publisher, err => {
                if (err) {
                    this.$emit("error", err);
                } else {
                    this.$emit("publisherConnected", publisher);
                }
            });
        };


        if (this.session && this.session.isConnected()) {
            // console.log("this.session && this.session.isConnected()")

            publish();

            // console.log(publisher)
        }
        if (this.session) {
            console.log("this.session")
            console.log(publisher)
            this.session.on("sessionConnected", publish);

        }

        if(!this.session){
            console.log("!this.session")
        }
    },
    beforeDestroy: function(){
        console.log("before destroy");
        console.log(publisher)
        console.log(publish)
        //here is where I want to KEEEEEL!
        // console.log(publisher)
        // console.log(this.session)
    }
};
</script>
```